# The requested theme does not exist. Stylesheet is missing - error after changing style.css name to my-styles.css in wp child theme?

Tags: themes, css, child-theme

I renamed `style.css` to `my-style.css`, but now I am getting an error in WordPress:

> "The requested theme does not exist. Stylesheet is missing."

I know the reason for that error, but how can I solve that without changing the stylesheet name again?

Answer (score 1):

Your theme must contain a style.css file, and it needs to have a comment at the top with the theme details.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

Comment: just i have changed name, sir. comments are at the top

Comment: 'Your theme must contain a style.css file'.. that't what i want to change

Comment: how to be get worked with changed name css file

Comment: You can't. Themes must have a style.css file. There's nothing stopping you putting your actual CSS in a separate file and enqueuing that. But you still need style.css. There is no fllter to change this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete style.css and have a functioning theme (at least without hacking WordPress core files). All the theme meta information is written in the style specifically. You can, however [register another css](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) file named `my-style.css` or whatever the name you want.

```
function my_theme_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory() . '/my-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_css' );
```

Now, your style.css does not have any css so you may want to remove it from your html. You can remove it from your site's `<head>` using  [wp_dequeue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/). But the physical file has to be there in your theme's directory.

```
add_action('init','_remove_style');

function _remove_style(){

    wp_dequeue_style('style.css'); 
}
```